# CCXT ByBit Close Position

Tags: python, position, ccxt

I am using ccxt to connect to ByBit and create orders.

```
symbol = 'SOLUSDT'
trade_res = exchange.create_order(symbol, amount=1, type='Market', side='Buy')
```

The above snippet buys 1 SOL against USDT. When I try to close the position by placing a sell order, I see that ByBit placed another Short position on SOL without closing the Long one (2 positions appear in the console):

[image]

How do I close a current position on ByBit using ccxt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `reduce_only` to `params` to exit out of a futures order

```
symbol = 'SOLUSDT'
trade_res = exchange.create_order(symbol, amount=1, type='Market', side='sell', params={'reduce_only': true})
```

---

On some exchanges, the parameter is `reduceOnly`

Comment: greatings to bybit, wonderfull docs :D